# Apache log4 J DB configuration for custom fields

Tags: java, mysql, apache

I have a project requirement where in we need to update DB with the logs.
So we have configured Apache log4j as below

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, DB

# Define the DB appender
log4j.appender.DB=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender

# Set JDBC URL
log4j.appender.DB.URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test

# Set Database Driver
log4j.appender.DB.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

# Set database user name and password
log4j.appender.DB.user=root
log4j.appender.DB.password=

# Set the SQL statement to be executed.
log4j.appender.DB.sql=insert into     coupon(couponId,customerName,date,level,message) values("%X{couponId}","%X{customerName}","%d","%p","%m")

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.DB.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

Since We have a requirement to update few custom fields in logs table along with the logs,we have called MDC as below

But after this configuration, insert statement fails due to below exception.

```
log4j:ERROR Failed to excute sql
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS': initialization started')' at line 1
```

As suggested in some blogs, have added the 5.1.29 version of m-sql-connector.jar  .

I am still getting the error.

```
public class DBLoggerTest {
    static Logger logger;

    public DBLoggerTest() {
        //System.setProperty("log4j.configuration", "log4j.properties");
        logger = Logger.getLogger(DBLoggerTest.class.getName());

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MDC.put("couponId",couponId);
        MDC.put("customerName",customerName);   
        logger.error("customer logs in");
        MDC.getContext().clear();
    }
}


CREATE TABLE coupon
(
    couponId varchar(25),
    customerName varchar(25),
    date Timestamp,
    level varchar(10),
    message varchar(2500),

);
```

Could you please suggest any solution for this error and also  suggest any pointers to update custom fields along with the logs.

Thanks
Kana

Answer (score 0):

You have used double quotes instead of single quotes for value string in log4j.properties for key log4j.appender.DB.sql

You should use single quotes for the same as below

```
log4j.appender.DB.sql=insert into coupon(couponId,customerName,date,level,message) values('%X{couponId}', '%X{customerName}', '%d', '%p', '%m')
```